# how to read XML node value or name c#

Tags: c#, xml

i have below xml.

```
<Data>
  <DateTime date="05-26-2016">
   <Time time="09:53:46 AM">Test1</Time>
</DateTime>
<DateTime date="05-27-2016">
<Time time="09:54:56 AM">Test2</Time>
</DateTime>
</Data>
```

i use below code to get the DateTime Name/Value but it is giving null.

```
xmlDoc.Load(@"E:\testdoc.xml");
XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
foreach (XmlElement a in rootNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            var attributeValue = a.GetAttribute("Value");
            if (a.Attributes["Value"].Value == attribute2.Value)
            {
                a.AppendChild(userChildNode2);
            }
        }
```

the required output for "attributeValue" should be "05-26-2016"/05-27-2016 in foreach loop. can some one let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Xml` there is no attribute with the name `Value`, that could be a reason you are receiving null.

```
a.GetAttribute("Value"); // Will return null.
```

I suggest, you could use `XDocument` and do this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);       
var fmatch = doc.Root.Elements("DateTime")
                      .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Attribute("date").Value == attribute2.Value);

if(fmatch!= null)
{
    fmatch.Add(new XElement("child", "value")); // use details you would like to add as an element. 
}

// add attribute in element use below

        if (fmatch != null)
        {
            fmatch.Add( new XElement("Time", new XAttribute("time", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")),"Test append in same date"));  
            doc.Save(@"E:\testdoc.xml");
        }
```

if you want to do it for all elements use `Where` clause

```
var matches = doc.Root.Elements("DateTime")
                      .Where(x=>x.Attribute("date").Value == attribute2.Value);

foreach(var match in matches)
{
    // logic here.
}
```

Take a look at this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNbBbM)

Comment: you have given xml contains as a string. but instead of input i have given xml path. it is giving me error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Something wrong with your `xml` just try opening with internet explorer or any other tool you can figure it out what is missing.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Data>
      <DateTime date="05-26-2016">
       <Time time="09:53:46 AM">Test1</Time>
    </DateTime>
    <DateTime date="05-27-2016">
    <Time time="09:54:56 AM">Test2</Time>
    </DateTime>
    </Data>

Comment: Are you using load method to supply filename? check my updated answer.

Comment: but when i am using this in foreach loop when the value matches with the DateTime (if (a.Attributes["Value"].Value == attribute2.Value)) then i need to appen the it as child. how can i compare and add

Comment: i also tried with this but no luck. var aaaa = a.Attributes["Name"]; or var aaaa = a.Attributes["Value"];

Comment: i tried XDocument from above. and i am in middle of xml update. i already have a code below for which i need to append the xml node.
            XmlNode userChildNode2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Time");
            XmlAttribute childattribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("time");
            childattribute.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
            userChildNode2.Attributes.Append(childattribute);
            userChildNode2.InnerText = "Test append in same date";        
from above ur code how can i append (child,value)

Comment: added below code and now it is working fine
            if (fmatch != null)
            {
                fmatch.Add( new XElement("Time", new XAttribute("time", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")),"Test append in same date")); // use details you would like to add as an element. 
                doc.Save(@"E:\testdoc.xml");
            }